# Nuget and Source Control Files to Exclude?

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I know I should be using nuget more but at this point I don't completely understand the nuances so I still tend to either get source and build the project, then reference the project, or I create my own "dlls" folder and hand copy the dll's in.

As part of my learning process, I'm trying to understand what is critical and what is not when using nuget.  For example, I've done install-package restsharp and now when I check into source control, I get files like "packages/RestSharp.103.4/lib/net4/RestSharp.xml".  I'm assuming that nuget will help me with upgrading and such and it needs to have certain meta data type files.

My question is:  Should I be ignoring any or all files in the "packages" directory? If so, what and why.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two workflows for handling this situation. The original workflow was to commit all files (you don't need to ignore any) in the packages directory so that other developers on your team would have the packages to build the project.

The newer workflow, available since NuGet 1.6, is to enable NuGet's package restore feature for a solution. This will cause any missing package files to be automatically downloaded when building the project, but now you no longer have to commit large binary files to your version control. As of NuGet 2.0, it is now [required](http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html) to have each developer on your team enable NuGet's package restore permission inside the Visual Studio options.

Comment: Every developer does not need to enable package restore.  The `.nuget` folder should be committed.  In addition, all projects in the solution are modified to include the `NuGet.targets` file.  During each build, missing packages are detected and downloaded from whatever NuGet repo is configured.

Comment: does this mean I can safely ignore the packages folder if I have a .nuget folder enabled?

Comment: @PeterKellner Yes. But you do need to commit the packages.config file as well as the .nuget folder that Sumo mentioned.

Comment: @Sumo As of NuGet 2.0, you do have to enable the package restore option in the Visual Studio options. I edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, under Project, there is a menu item called `Enable NuGet Package Restore`.  This is available when you have a project open and you are using **Web Application Projects** (restore does not work with Web Site Projects).  Select that and enable package restore.  Then, you do not need to commit the Packages directory to source control anywhere.

NuGet's documentation has much more information on [package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

If you want to possibly mimic package restore manually, you will need something that parses the `packages.config` file and then executes the [NuGet Commandline Bootstrapper](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/58939) (`nuget.exe`) to install those packages.  Luckily the bootstrapper takes a packages.config as a parameter.  Using the following steps should restore your packages:

1. Create a `packages` folder off of the directory where the solution is.
2. From the packages directory run the following from the command line:

   nuget.exe install [path to packages.config]

This can all be done from within a batch file or however you'd like to automate it.

Comment: I tried that and it warned me about it not working with web sites (just web applications).  The particular project I'm working on is huge and the thought of converting it to a Web app makes me almost ill (though I wish no one had ever showed me the web site project in the first place).  So, what are the implications for this? any thoughts?

Comment: In that case (probably should have been mentioned as part of the original question), you're only option is to commit the Packages folder and the packages.config.  NuGet explicitly does not support Web site projects [at the moment](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1663).

Comment: @Peter Kellner, I updated my answer to give you an option with Web Site Projects that might work at least until you can [convert to a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (not as painful as you might think).

Comment: So, I see in my packages directory a file called "repositories.config"  in the packages directory. I DO NOT need to keep that?  I see a packages.config in each of my project directories.  I assume I want that one? I'm a little nervous that it is putting Jquery, modernizr, etc. in all my projects. Will it cause those to get added now (not my plan and will likely cause things to break)

Comment: @Peter Kellner, you do not need to keep the `repositories.config`.  The packages.config will only reside in projects that you have added dependencies via the package manager.  You may need to use something like [NuGetPowerTools](http://nuget.org/packages/NuGetPowerTools) as this was recommended before it was built into NuGet.